# Will redhat yum see packages installed with rpm?

Tags: redhat, yum

Or if not, is there a way to make yum be aware of them? Does 'rpm -qa' and 'yum list installed' query the same source?

Comment: You should be able to test this yourself quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yum is aware of packages that are installed or updated via the rpm command.  As proof for example you could manually install an outdated version of a package that is available in an upstream repository via `rpm -ivh <package>` and then run `yum clean all && yum update` and it'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Both command uses rpm db files under /var/lib/rpm/, yum is a only a python script to manipulate the rpms